# Category Not Recognizing Ivars

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, categories, objective-c-category

I have quite a large View Controller in my app and I want to clean it up by separating some of the functions into categories. I read up on how to implement a category and have:

```
#import "StatsVC.h"

@interface StatsVC (TableViewDelegate)

@end
```

As my .h (the category is called StatsVC+TableViewDelegate).
and my Implemation starts like this:

```
@implementation StatsVC (TableViewDelegate)
```

Several times in the category, I access variables which are iVars of the original class.I have read and supposedly this is allowed, but for every use of an iVar in the category I get this error message:

`'Use of undeclared identifier 'iVar'`

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely can access instance variables from methods in a category. Categories add methods to the class -- there's no real difference at run time between a method declared in the class interface and one declared in a category on that class. You'll probably need to show more code to get a good answer. Right now, my top two guesses are:

1. You're trying to access ivars from a class method rather than an instance method, i.e. one starting with a `+` instead of a `-`.
2. There's something wrong with the way you've declared the ivars.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, The ivars are created with properties and then are synthesized. The methods that are in the Category are all tableViewDelegate methods. Here's an example: @property (nonatomic, strong) Session *selectedSession; is its declaration in the class. In the category I access it like so: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return (2 + [[selectedSession pieceSession] count]);
}

Comment: In that case the ivars really aren't declared in the category -- it only sees the .h file so has no way to tell what the ivars might be. Since you're using properties, you should most likely use the properties in your category methods instead of accessing ivars directly. If you want to access the ivars directly, declare them yourself in the class interface.

Comment: Thanks A lot Caleb, this did the trick. Too bad you can't access the synthesized ivars without declaring them from a category...

Comment: In practice it's not a big limitation. If you're using a property, directly accessing the ivar is probably asking for trouble.